# generate a minesweeping grid in c

Tags: c, arrays, grid, generator

The first part of my assignment is creating a random minesweeping game grid where * would represents a mine and . a safe cell. The user has to input the dimensions m n of the grid and the probability p of each cell containing a mine.

The problem is when using a random generator to determine weather a cell has a mine or not, I find my self obliged (as far as I know, which isn't far) to create a 2d array of type double using 1s and 0s instead of * and dots. I can't seem to convert this into a 2d array of type char... this is my code so far... any hints advice or straight up solution would be greatly appreciated! I am very new to this.

```
int main()
{

    double grid[MAX][MAX];
    int i,j,m,n;
    double p;

    printf("Please enter your grid size: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    printf("Please enter the probability of each cell containing a mine (0-1):");
    scanf("%lf", &p);

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX;
                if (grid[i][j] < p) 
                grid[i][j] = 1;
                else if (grid[i][j] >= p)
                grid[i][j] = 0;
            printf("%.0lf", grid[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start with a `grid` of `char` all set to `'.'`. Use a temporary variable to store the random value. If the value is less than `p`, set the appropriate entry in the `grid` to `'*'`

Comment: ok thks ill give it a try !

Comment: At least, you have to check if the `m` and `n` entered values are upper than `0` and lower than `MAX` and if `p` is in range of [0.0-1.0]. You can use only a single `if-else` to set the grid at `1.0` or `0.0`.